# why all images are not going out of screen because I want to create a image slider? inshort why images are not going out of screen?

Tags: html, css

why all images are not going out of screen because I want to create a image slider?
I have tried display flex and all images are going out of screen but with float its not going out of screen.

```css
.container > img{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/29/03/02/bo-leaf-5351180__340.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/13/13/28/house-5651866__340.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/10/01/12/31/solothurn-4518117__340.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/10/14/38/leaves-5643327__340.png" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah they will not go out of screen obviously if you are using **float** coz with ```float:left``` you are forcing all img to adhere to the left of the container,and if its working with **flex** then why are you even using float ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should simply using the flex properties

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row
}
```